# Create now/subtract dates/month with format of "2014-08-04T17:19:00-07:00" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format, momentjs

How do I create the time `now` and format it to a string with format of "2014-08-04T17:19:00-07:00"? Using moment.js or any other JavaScript?

I will also need to create 2 new, one to subtract a week from now, one to subtract a month from now, but also with this format.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough:

```
var d = Date.now(); //For current time in MS
d = new Date(); //For current time wrapped in the object.
d.toISOString();
```

For more on ISO String read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) or [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

If you want to do any Date arithmetic, like adding a month, just add/subtract the number of milliseconds for that unit to your date object.

Additionally, if you don't want time in Zulu, you can use String manipulation to drop the Z and add the proper zone. Don't forget to account for the difference in time zones!

Comment: Hi, I also tried to use your method. When I do it in console. it's good as expected. However, during teaspoon running, it becomes to 1970,Jan, 1 00:00  Is there anyway I can do it please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with teaspoon. However, if Date.now() is working, you can try doing `var d = new Date( Date.now() );` And see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString();

> "2014-08-05T17:22:08.030Z"

// Subtract one week:
var before = date;
before.setDate(date.getDate()-7);
before.toISOString();

> "2014-07-29T17:22:08.030Z"
```

Comment: Hi, I used your method. When I do it in console. it's good as expected. However, during teaspoon running, it becomes to 1970,Jan, 1 00:00  Is there anyway I can do it please? Thanks.

Comment: What becomes 1970? The first date or the second one?

Comment: I tried both "createdAt: (new Date()).toISOString()" and "createdAt: moment().toISOString()". They are good when I open  a console and type, but when I put a debugger in it and pause teaspoon, it gives some dates in "1969-12-31T08:00:00.000Z"

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar to teaspoon, bt maybe you have this problem because it is using some other lib or is evaluating data on a server, then the new Date is setted to the default 1970 date.